# List folders and subfolder but not files

Tags: php

I researched but didn't find my answer, do you know how to find all folders and subfolders like this but NOT files ?

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="/Folder1">Folder 1</a></li>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="/Folder1/Subfolder1">Subfolder 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="/Folder1/Subfolder2">Subfolder 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="/Folder1/Subfolder3">Subfolder 3</a></li>
       </ul>
   <li><a href="/Folder2">Folder 2</a></li>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="/Folder2/Subfolder1">Subfolder 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="/Folder2/Subfolder2">Subfolder 2</a></li>
       </ul>
   <li><a href="/Folder3">Folder 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I found this code on stackoverflow but it shows the files and I don't know how to do the path folder for the a href :

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
$ffs = scandir($dir);

unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);

// prevent empty ordered elements
if (count($ffs) < 1)
    return;

echo '<ol>';
foreach($ffs as $ff){
    echo '<li>'.$ff;
    if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);

    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ol>';
}
listFolderFiles('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Test');
```

Comment: Can you show us examples of your research?

Comment: Consider using the [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php).

Comment: $dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');

echo '<ul>';
for($i=0;$i<count($dirs);$i++){
 echo '<li><a href="#">'.$dirs[$i].'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

That's what I made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if file is directory:

```
foreach($ffs as $ff){

  if (!is_dir($ff)) {
     continue;
  }

  echo '<li>'.$ff;
  if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
  echo '</li>';
}
```